# Component Exception; Can't find variable: style

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to javaScript and am having an interesting problem. Here is some context; I am running windows 10, node v15, I have downloaded expo and am using visual studio. The command I am using to run my code is npm start.

The error I am getting says it "cannot find the variable: style" and points to this line in Welcome.js( line 6 or 7)

```
<View style={[style.button, {backgroundColor: props.color}]}>
```

I started to think it dealt with my imports but now not so much! I am pretty sure its a simple stupid mistake, but what do I know! Any help at all is appreciated. Thank you for the patience and I apologize for the ignorance!
Let me know if there is anything else I can provide that could help, Thanks.

App.js code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import Welcomebutton from './src/pages/Welcome';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Please work</Text>
        <Welcomebutton text='Welcome' color='red' />
      </View>
      
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  title: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20

  }
});
```

Welcome.js <--- my welcome page that only consists of a non working button lol

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity  } from 'react-native';

const Welcomebutton = props => {
    const content = (
        <View style={[style.button, {backgroundColor: props.color}]}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{props.text}</Text>
        </View>
    )
    return <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>{content}</TouchableOpacity>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        padding: 16,
        width: 200,
        borderRadius: 24,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    text: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 20
    }
});

export default Welcomebutton;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// you made a small typo here
<View style={[style.button, {backgroundColor: props.color}]}>
```

```
// it should be styles.button not style.button
<View style={[styles.button, {backgroundColor: props.color}]}>
```

full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity  } from 'react-native';

const Welcomebutton = props => {
    const content = (
        <View style={[styles.button, {backgroundColor: props.color}]}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{props.text}</Text>
        </View>
    )
    return <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress}>{content}</TouchableOpacity>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    button: {
        padding: 16,
        width: 200,
        borderRadius: 24,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    text: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 20
    }
});

export default Welcomebutton;
```

Comment: oof, that one hurts. hahaha thank you I appreciate the response:)